# Haskell can't match type, claims rigid variable

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I am new to Haskell, and I am playing around with creating a typeclass for graphs and the nodes in them. Since I want both directed and undirected graphs, I have

```
data Node = Node { label :: Char
                 , index :: Int
                 } deriving (Ord, Eq)
type Graph edgeType = ([Node], [edgeType])
data Edge = DirectedEdge   {h :: Node, t :: Node}
          | UndirectedEdge {a :: Node, b :: Node}
instance Show Node where
    show n = ['(', label n, ')']
instance Show Edge where
    show (DirectedEdge   h t) = show h ++ "->" ++ show t
    show (UndirectedEdge a b) = show a ++ "-"  ++ show b
```

So I am distinguishing between directed and undirected edges. A graph must only have edges of either type. I also have the following:

```
nodes :: [Node]
nodes = zipWith Node ['a'..] [0..]

emptyGraph :: [Node] -> Graph edgeType
emptyGraph ns = (ns, [])
```

So far so good, however I am writing a function `connect`, with connects a node to an existing graph. Ideally, I only want it to apply to undirected graphs, but that doesn't seem to be an option. Instead, I have something like this:

```
connect :: Graph edgeType -> Node -> Graph edgeType
connect (ns, es) n = (n:ns, e:es)
    where e = UndirectedEdge n (head ns)
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `edgeType' with `Edge'
  `edgeType' is a rigid type variable bound by
             the type signature for
               connect :: Graph edgeType -> Node -> Graph edgeType
```

What is the best way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to have two separate edge types instead of `Edge`

```
newtype DirectedEdge = DirectedEdge { h :: Node, t :: Node}
newtype UndirectedEdge = UndirectedEdge { a :: Node, b :: Node}
```

And you probably want some kind of typeclass that gives you back a `(Node, Node)` given an arbitrary edge:

```
class HasNodeEndpoints a where
  endpoints :: a -> (Node, Node)

-- obvious instances for DirectedEdge and UndirectedEdge
```

Then when you want to talk about arbitrary graphs, you will write functions that work on `Graph a`, and probably on `HasNodeEndpoints a => Graph a`.  Algorithms that care about the graph kind would work on  `Graph DirectedEdge`  and `Graph UndirectedEdge` for directed and undirected graphs, respectively.

Another natural extension would be labeled directed and undirected edges.

```
class HasLabeled a where
  type Label a -- associated type synonym
  label :: a -> Label a
  updateLabel :: a -> (Label a -> Label a) -> a

-- now define data types and instances for labeled directed and undirected edges
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you choose a specific edge type, namely `Edge`, when you use `UndirectedEdge`, the result is that your graph is no longer polymorphic in the edge type. It has to have the type:

```
connect :: Graph Edge -> Node -> Graph Edge
connect (ns, es) n = (n:ns, e:es)
    where e = UndirectedEdge n (head ns)
```

Since there's noo other type your edges can be, given that clear use of `UndirectedEdge`.

---

As an aside, I'd use strictness annotations on the nodes, just as a matter of good hygiene:

```
data Node = Node { label :: !Char
                 , index :: !Int
                 } deriving (Ord, Eq)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can have `combine` _only_ apply to undirected graphs as I have defined them? `connect :: Graph UndirectedEdge -> Node -> Graph UndirectedEdge` does not work.

Comment: @Jordan That doesn't work because `UndirectedEdge` is a "constructor" and not a "type".  You need to look at a solution along the lines of what Lambdageek suggests, splitting Edge into two distinct types.